# Where is "edge compute" actually located?

Tags: internet, datacenter, isp, infrastructure

Sorry, if the question is a bit basic, but I must be missing the relevant search terms, because most of the resources I could find about edge computing talk about it in abstract marketing terms. I understand that edge computing is supposed to be done either outside or on the edge of the "cloud", but where exactly does the "cloud" begin and end isn't really clear to me.

Where are the edge nodes physically located? Are the edge nodes still located inside normal/primary datacenters, but are somehow just closer to the network? Are there some edge-specific mini-datacenters which are smaller, but there are more of them? Or is this compute somehow scattered among the existing internet routing infrastructure?

How "dense" (geographically) are these edge nodes? Does every large city have its own "edge datacenter"? Every small country/state? Every big country/region?

If the edge infrastructure is geographically sparse (few big datacenters), how is it any different from conventional "cloud" infrastructure distributed over a couple of regional datacenters (us-east-1, us-east-2, us-west-1, us-west-2, etc).

If the edge infrastructure is geographically dense (many small datacenters), how is it even remotely cost-effective for anything more complex than simply serving static, long-lived content? Even if you are Netflix, renting/owning rack space in each major city and supporting such a non-localized infrastructure sounds like it shouldn't be viable.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if the people who downvoted the question could explain, why they did so, and how can I improve my question.

Comment: Your question seriously lacks research effort. Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_computing

Comment: @Zac67 I read the wikipedia page before opening the question. I am even referencing some of the claims that wikipedia makes in paragraphs 2 and 3. The wikipedia article doesn't answer my questions. It's all extremely hand-wavy and non-specific. The closest it comes to giving an answer is saying that edge computing exploits "smart objects, mobile phones, or network gateways", but a) this doesn't make sense, I know that cloudflare services are not running on my phone or any of my IoT devices and b) even if this is true, this explanation is not detailed enough for me. E.g. whose gateways?

Comment: Also, even if you don't like how my question is worded, it is **definitely not** "opinion-based". I am asking about purely factual information. Edge computing exists. Various companies provide edge computing services. These services certainly run on some real hardware somewhere in the world. All I am asking is to explain which hardware that is, where is it located (geographically, not metaphoricallly "on the edge of the network"), who owns this hardware etc etc.

Comment: Is there any way for me to contest the reason of closure for my question? Edit: found the relevant help page. I think, I've already explained my disagreement with the "opinion-based" status.

Comment: There's [meta] but I don't think contesting would help.

Comment: @Zac67 Thank you for the pointer. I think I'll wait for a bit in case someone votes to reopen before posting on Meta.

Comment: `Even if you are Netflix, renting/owning rack space in each major city and supporting such a non-localized infrastructure sounds like it shouldn't be viable.` how would you know? Netflix is probably the exemplar reference standard for global content distribution. Did you even glance at their architecture? Or is this a drive by stream of consciousness spew?

Comment: @GregAskew "how would I know?" You're right, I wouldn't know. That's why I am asking this question. It's part of a hypothetical that explains what I don't understand. I don't know the exact details of how their infrastructure works and don't understand how are they able to make it work (if they actually do have a datacenter in every major city in the world). Also, I'll admit that I am employing Cunningham's Law here.

Answer (score 2):

This a response to help you refine question.

First thing to understand is there is no actual techinical definition of "Cloud" or "Edge". These are just marketing terms that have taken on a life of their own.

What these terms really mean:

Cloud - Some server(s) somewhere else.

Edge Computing - Some server(s) located either on-prem or nearer to on-prem than the chosen "Cloud" servers.

Why have Edge? Because for all the marketing hype - you can't count on the internet.

Upstream - So, if there is realtime data you MUST to get to the cloud you need to queue it up to ensure 100% transfer. IIOT is a driver for this market. CDN drives the need in the downstream direction.

Downstream - Static or almost static content that is easily cached takes the load from internet or servers father away.

There is no single answer. When experts start talking about x number of hops without the context of the application, IMHO the abstract completely loses touch with reality. It isn't about the "hop" as it either protecting from points of failure, relieving bandwidth / lantency, etc.

Some of the wording of your question seems more like routing rather than servers. If that is case, the focus is speed and lantency. The assumption is the fewer hops, the faster speed and less lantency.

Comment: "Edge" is all about getting computing services closer to the customer (than a central cloud), complemental to content delivery networks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "Some server(s) located either on-prem or nearer to on-prem than the chosen "Cloud" servers". My understanding is that "on-perm" only makes sense when you are providing a service to a company that already has their own datacenter. For example, when web developers talk about reducing the time to "First Contentful Paint" by moving the web server/database to "the edge", how is that done? There is no "on-prem" in this case (unless I am misunderstanding something).

Comment: Think about a modern manufacturing facility of any industrial scale. There will be a dozens of machines with a total of hundreds of data points generating thousands of data points. If it is truly important to them to capture, store, analysis, and do whatever with this data, then they need to decide if gaps in the data are acceptable. With  1.) the likelihood that the data is going to the cloud and 2.) low cost of quality servers. Having an "Edge" server to store and forward to ensure all the data makes to the cloud. It holds the data when the internet is down or degraded, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Does every existing ISP coordinate with every existing cloud provider to
> achieve this "two hops" ideal?

No. You miss the "ideal" and ignore that. Also, Cloudflare is on all major providers. Azure has a lot of data centers that they offer local providers access to.